# How to access image downloaded from the web

Tags: java, android

I downloaded an image from the web using this code and saved it directly to the application specific internal storage.

```
is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
os = LoginActivity.this.openFileOutput(id + ".jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int read;
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
while ((read = is.read(data)) != -1)
    os.write(data, 0, read);
```

How do I access this stored image using `Drawable`? I attempted to open it using the following code but the operation resulted in a file not found exception.

```
File imgPath = new File(id + ".jpg");
profilePic.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imgPath.getPath()));
```

Comment: To say your time, just use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for image loading, and it will cache your image to memory and disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming you call os.close() in the following lines of your code*

You need to specify the path when instantiating your File object. Do the following :

```
File imgPath = new File(yourContext.getFilesDir(), id + ".jpg");
```

As said in doc of `getFilesDir()` method :

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.

Comment: File open still fails. Is it because the security mode is MODE_PRIVATE?

Comment: If it's same application trying to access the file, no problem. Is it ? Don't you have any error while creating and saving the file ? Do you call os.close in your code ?

Comment: I did. The file saved successfully. The error is:
12-07 20:01:11.860: E/BitmapFactory(18762): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.innolabmm.discoverlioncity/files/558245720.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: How do you know your file is saved successfully ? May you log the id when saving it to be sure it is the same ? You also may want to try from the DDMS with a rooted device (real or virtual like Genymotion) to browse your /data/data/com.innolabmm.discoverlioncity to try to discover where your file is saved exactly.

Comment: I've found the error. The id was null at the time downloaded started so it was saved as null.jpg. I'll try to fix it. Thanks for your time gahfy. You really solved my problem.